# Avoiding sleep when lid is close and no one is logged in

Tags: laptop, centos, sleep, power-management, centos-6

I've an old Dell Latitude laptop that I've converted to CentOS 6.5. As this is going to work like a server (i.e. no one will use it directly) I've changed from UI the power management option to ignore lid closed.

Now the odd is that if I'm logged in into OS that work properly, if I close the lid the machine still works, however if I close the lid when no one is connected then the laptop is going to sleep more or less immediately.

How can I prevent CentOS to go to sleep when the lid is closed AND no one is logged in?

Thank you.